# How to solve invalid IMEI problem in LG G3?

Tags: lg-g3, imei, menu, hidden

After performing a factory reset on my LG G3, my IMEI was set to 0. This problem has been reported also in xda-forums.

How to reset the IMEI in LG G3 running on Android Marshmallow 6.0?

Answer (score 2):

A solution for this problem has been given in multiple sources, such as: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2lHFy7AciE), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzRoP_8Xf5I), and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkzYDbZ-pK0). However, in those cases either the phone model is different, or the Android version on the device is different.

Solving this problem requires couple of steps:

**0) Setup description**

**1) Accessing the hidden menu for LG G3 on Android Marshmallow 6.0 & enable DIAG MODE**

The solution for this is given in the following xda [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/lg-g3-how-to-enable-diag-mode-t3457718)

Basically, following steps 1-7 from that post was sufficient for me (given that I had installed the latest version of LG drivers: *LGMobileDriver_WHQL_Ver_4.2.0.exe*)

> 1. Download LG United Mobile Driver or LG Mobile Driver. (I don't think it matters.
> 2. Install it.
> 3. Go to Device Manager on your Windows Machine.
> 4. Physically Connect your phone to the computer and set it to CHARGE ONLY (This is necessary).
> 5. , Then Go to your phone Dialer PAD and type in the code: *#546368#*855# (Replace 855 with the LG G3 model Number - 855 is the international model)
>
>    - It should automatically launch you to the hidden Menu.
> 6. Navigate to USB > PORT CHECK TEST. (Not sure if this is necessary at all...but won't hurt to enable it anyway.. you may skip this or
>      not..it depends..idk)
>
>    - Enable it
> 7. Then Navigate back to USB > QMICMSet
>
>    - Click 'OK'. ( Immediately you should see TWO Notifications Display: "LGE Android Phone" Under "Other Devices" with a yellow exclamation.

**2) Use QPST to modify the IMEI**

For this you have to use the proper version of QPST, that is: 2.7.378. The required software can be found here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/figdbxb75j5kyry/package.rar

For the remaining steps you can follow everything after 06:00 from the afore-mentioned video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2lHFy7AciE), or steps 1-28 after this line:

> [After it you will have a 2G network but no 3G\4G network because of
>   the imei of the device is 0.So you must restore it with QPST.

in this post: https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/general/service-disabled-current-version-t3403232

> 1. Make sure you LG G3 is running the stock LG firmware [..] If your phone does not have official firmware
>      installed on it, restore it to stock first. Install the latest LG USB
>      drivers on your computer.
> 2. Now download the IMEI converter tool and unzip it.
> 3. Download QPST (Qualcomm Product Support Tools) and unzip it.
> 4. Open the QPST_2.7_378 and run the setup file to install it on your computer.
> 5. Enable USB debugging on your device. You can find this option under Settings> Developer options. Connect your device to the computer.
> 6. Run QPST configuration and click on Ports tab. Click on Add new port option.
> 7. Your current port should show as COM4/5.
> 8. Select the port and click OK. The port should come up on active phones.
> 9. Select the phone and click the Software Download option from Start clients menu.
> 10. Now click on Backup tab. You should see your phone’s port.
> 11. Click on Start to initiate backup.
> 12. Now navigate to C:/ Program Files/ qualcomm/ qpst/bin folder.
> 13. Run RF_NV_Manager.
> 14. Click File> Read from phone. Your phone’s IMEI number should appear on number 550; NV_IMEI_I
> 15. If you do not see item 550, do not panic.
> 16. Click on File> Read supported RF NV items.
> 17. Click on item 550. You would see 9 blank fields.
> 18. Now run IMEI Converter.exe.
> 19. Now type your phone’s IMEI in Enter IMEI field. You can find your IMEI on your phone’s bill or the box your device came in.
> 20. Then click on  button.
> 21. You should see 18 digits in groups of 9.
> 22. In RF_NV_Manager program, click on Hex by Write NV button.
> 23. In the 9 boxes, type in the numbers from IMEI converter starting from left. Type in first group of two numbers in the first field, then
>       go to the next field and type in second 2 digits.
> 24. When you are done with doing this, click on Write NV option.
> 25. Then click File> Read from phone.
> 26. Item number 550 should appear now.
> 27. Disconnect the USB cable and reboot it.
> 28. Open phone’s dialer and dial *#06#. You should see your phone’s IMEI now.

Credit for the solution goes to the original authors in xda and yt, I just put together their stuff.